# Programmer: Effects of pauses on stress

Tags: stress

I'm a programmer by profession. In the course of my daily routine, I observe that I'd have to frequently "wait" for the computer to do something, before I can continue with my work.

Empirically, I'd say that I'd have to interrupt myself in such fashion every 10 minutes. These frequent interruptions stress me out.

Is any one aware of any scientific study that measures the impact on such interruptions on an individual's stress levels?

Comment: Hi Jiraiya, I am sorry but questions about the behavior of an individual are considered off-topic on this SE and is likely to be closed. If you could reformulate your question to be applicable to a wider audience, AND if you provide some initial research (i.e frame it within Psychological science) the question may become on-topic. Considering your question, [this](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0018720813504216) paper may be a nice start. It describes how people tend to start multitasking when delays increase (as an effect of a Decreased workload).

Comment: Ask couple of your colleage and make a systematic study, and report it here, maybe we can discuss about it, I am also a developer and it is interesting for me to know more about it